# Find Enumarable Rows in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
foreach (String s in AvailableInAB)
{
    DataRow cmp = c.NewRow();
    Object[] Itr = cmp.ItemArray;
    EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> rst = from mrow in a.AsEnumerable() 
                                           where mrow.Field<String>("Part Number") == s 
                                           select mrow;
    if (rst.ToList().Count > 0)
    {
        rst.ToList()[0].ItemArray.CopyTo(Itr, 0);
    }
}
```

My code will fetch the Respected Item from the a Table .Its working fine .
But What i need is if the Same string name "S" repeats mean the code fetching the first value that matched in the Query .It will jump the first line item and find the Second perfect match if the name repeats .Please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Please clarify

Comment: The query will fetch the item from table if the (S)name exits in a datarow.If the same name repeats the query fetch the same item.I want to get the match after the first match .

Comment: like in to get the second item?

Comment: Try following : DataTable rst = a.AsEnumerable().Where(mrow =>  mrow.Field<String>("Part Number") == s).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: sample data and expected results please. i find it hard to ***grammatically*** understand your question.

Comment: Geoman -Sorry for That.Actually What my need is the Query Extract the item if the name in the column matches to s.if the loop again gives the same name then the query jump the first item and give the second match.But it always gives the first item .